# Deleting last message on a message send discord.js

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Hope that you are having a good day, I am working on a discord.js bot (in typescript) and would like it to always be the last message in the channel. Ex: Someone sends a message, the bot deletes it's last message and sends a new one. I tried this:  `message.channel.send('This is a sticked message').then(msg => { setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 3000) })` but this just does it in an amount of time and is not triggering when another message is sent, I tried a lot of other things with storing the message in a variable. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [messageCreate event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate) to listen for messages.

Look into [MessageManager.fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) to get your last message.

A small example would be like this:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  if (msg.channel.id === "channelIdHere") {
    if (msg.author.id === client.user.id) return; // if your bot sent the last message, do nothing
    const lastMessages = await msg.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }); // 100 is the limit; if you're updating it every message you probably shouldn't have an issue with this
    lastMessages.forEach((msg) => {
      if (msg.author.id == client.user.id) {
        msg.delete(); // remove any messages in those last 100 made by your bot - this should only be 1 message if you update it each time, though
      }
      msg.channel.send("text");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello! I fixed a couple typos and ended up with this https://pastebin.com/LvhM1Hju my issue is that when I try this I get an error https://pastebin.com/8UzfFUJj if you know what is wrong please notify me, thanks for all the help <3

Comment: Oops, I accidentally used `filter` over `forEach`, I'll edit the answer to make it correct